# Beamer Hyperref to picture - Linux

Tags: beamer, hyperref, linux

from within my Beamer-PDF-presentation I'd like to start a gallery-slideshow with my standard picture-viewer on Linux Mint.

My code looks kind of like this:

```
\begin{frame}

    \begin{itemize}
    \centering
    \item \alert<+>{\textbf{ \href{run:home/michael/Schreibtisch/StaVer_17/1_15_WoeLa/DSC03211.JPG}{Bild 2015} }}
....
\end{itmeize}
\end{frame}
```

But when I try this my PDF-Viewer says "...file not found".
But what I wanted was to open a separate window (parallel to the PDF-presentation) with the picture popping up and navigate trough the folder containing this picture.

Thank you in advance.

Michael

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Can you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake....
The root-directory was missing in the beginning of the path... :(

The correct syntax is:

```
\href{run:/path/to/the/wanted/file.jpg}{Link-text in the frame}
```

This works perfectly fine